# Show a new select for option selected dynamically jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="options">foo</label>
   <select class="form-control"  name="options" multiple>
     <option value="">-- Choice --</option>
     <option value="opt1">test1</option>
     <option value="opt2">test2</option>
     <option value="opt3">test3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#scope_new_system").change(function() {
     var allSelected = new Array();
     $("#scope_new_system option:selected").each(function() {
       allSelected.push(this.value);
     });
  });
</script>
```

I'm trying to dynamically generate a select with different options based on options selected on the multiple select named "options" above. For example if I click on option test 1 then a select element with options shows to select an option. If I select test 2 then another select shows because I now have 2 options selected. Finally if I unclicked test 1 select option goes away and if i do the same with test 2 it also goes away as well and i'm left with nothing selected. Please help!.

Comment: and where is `#scope_new_system` element on your code??

Comment: forgot to edit that part. I will correct my code now.

Comment: So the relation between the two `select` just to show/hide it?? or `select 2` values depending on `select 1` values?? I didn't got that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```js
$('#selectpicker').multiselect();
$('#selectpicker').on('change',function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('.hidden_slc').hide();
  for (x in val) {
    $('#based'+val[x]).show();
  }
})
```

```html
<style>
  .hidden_slc {
    display: none;
   }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<select id="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option value='1'>tes1</option>
  <option value='2'>tes2</option>
  <option value='3'>tes3</option>
</select>

<select id="based1" class='hidden_slc'>
  <option>sample_from_1</option>
  <option>sample</option>
</select>
<select id="based2" class='hidden_slc'>
  <option>sample_from_2</option>
  <option>sample</option>
</select>
<select id="based3" class='hidden_slc'>
  <option>sample_from_3</option>
  <option>sample</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```js
var allSelected = [];

$("#scope_new_system").on("change",function() {
    var allSelected = new Array();
    $("#scope_new_system option:selected").each(function(){
        allSelected.push(this.value);
        
    });
    console.log(allSelected)
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="options">foo</label>
   <select id="scope_new_system" class="form-control"  name="options" multiple>
     <option value="">-- Choice --</option>
      <option value="opt1">test1</option>
      <option value="opt2">test2</option>
      <option value="opt3">test3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I just released I missed that id there but that doesn't solve what I want to do. I'm able to get the value of the options selected by using $('#div').html(allSelected) but I want to show a different option everytime a selection is made and dismiss it if is not select.

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you use dynamic option try to use on("click") instead of .click()

Comment: That doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

**As I pointed** *So the relation between the two `select`s just to show/hide it?? or `select` 2 values depending on `select` 1 values?? I didn't got that point*

**But sure Your 1st step is:** To check for `option:selected` length by using `$("option:selected" , this).length;` or `$(this).find("option:selected").length;`

```js
$("#scope_new_system").change(function() {
  var allSelected = [],
      num_of_selected_option = $("option:selected" , this).length;
  if(num_of_selected_option == 0){
    // if nothing selected
    alert('Nothing Selected');
  }else if(num_of_selected_option == 1){
    // if just one selected
    allSelected = [this.value];
    alert('Just one value selected : '+allSelected);
  }else if(num_of_selected_option > 1){
    // if more than one selected
    $("option:selected" , this).each(function(){
      allSelected.push(this.value);
    });
    alert('Selected Values : '+allSelected);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="options">foo</label>
  <select id="scope_new_system" class="form-control"  name="options" multiple>
   <option value="">-- Choice --</option>
    <option value="opt1">test1</option>
    <option value="opt2">test2</option>
    <option value="opt3">test3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: see the changes i made. that what i want to accomplish but now i have a different problem. The selects don't go away went nothing is selected.

Comment: @MayrenMartinez edit your question .. you forgot and edited my answer